# Tail event, convergence of series

Tags: probability

How to prove, that $\{ \omega : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k(\omega) \text{ is finite} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2, \ldots )$ where $\mathcal{F}_i=\sigma(X_i) = \{ X_i^{-1} (B) : B \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R^n})\}$
Please write as many details as possible, I would like to understand clearly.

Comment: I suppose your set ought to be defined as $\{ \omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k(\omega) \text{ exists } \}$.

Comment: Your title mentions "tail event", but your question doesn't use this concept. Did you copy the question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the fact that $\ell_1$ is separable, let $\{(x_{k,n})_{k=1}^\infty \}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a dense subset of summable sequences in $\ell_1$.

Denote by $A$ the event $\{ \omega : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k(\omega) \text{ is finite} \}$. For $\omega\in A$, the sequence $(X_k(\omega))$ is in $\ell_1$, hence there are elements $(y_k)$ and $(z_k)$ of $\ell_1$ such that $y_k \le X_k(\omega)\le z_k$, and thus, we may find such elements in our dense set. This observation allows to write event $A$ the following way:
$$
A = \bigcup_{m,n\ge1} \bigcap_{k\ge1} \{\omega: x_{k,m} \le X_k(\omega) \le x_{k,n}\}
$$

Since each $ \{\omega: x_{k,m} \le X_k(\omega) \le x_{k,n}\} \in \sigma(X_k)$, it follows that $A\in \sigma(X_1, X_2,\ldots)$.

Comment: How do you define $y_k \le X_k(\omega)\le z_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$?

Comment: I assumed that $X_k$ is a random variable. If $X_k$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can apply above proof to each component, which suffices. Alternatively, use standard lattice order on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Well the OP used $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I guess he wants a general result.

Comment: This argument is wrong. You cannot guarantee that such sequences exist.